# Is there a way to implement drag & drop in a phonegap angular js project?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, cordova

I have tried this one: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop together with touchpunch (http://touchpunch.furf.com/). On the browser it is working fine but when I deploy the app to an android device I receive following error:

$ui.mouse is not defined

Are there other alternatives to implement drag & drop for this combination ?

Answer (score 0):

touchpunch requires jquery ui plugin. Verify if you included jquery UI in your page.

Comment: I have included jquery ui with bower and I am loading it into my project with require.js